# CSS, HTML: What's the best way to add space to the inside of a scrollable element?

Tags: html, css, layout, space

Both horizontally and vertically?

I am using jquery ui's draggable feature constrained within a div, and I need a large internal area to work with.

Comment: Well, I'll just describe my usage needs.  Hope that helps.

Comment: depending on the element, what you want to achieve, your current code..give more info, is very general question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `padding` on the scrollable element and then use `margin`'s on the children.

Comment: Ah this works too.  I just found a way involving long 1px children that also works as well, but I think I'll use this.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is what you are looking for. Here's a little guide to using it.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

There is also a guide to the "box model" which will come in handy learning how margins, borders, padding etc. effect a element. It's on the left navigation panel of the link above (I can't post 2 links)